Find the matrix with respect to the canonical basis of the orthogonal projection of $R^3$ on $S$
I have a doubt. First I need to obtain the orthogonal projection of $R^3$ onto $S$, where $S$ is: $S=span{(1 0 -1),(0 1 -1)}$
and then the coordinate matrix with respect to the canonical basis of $R^3$. I don't understand what I have to do. If I calculate the orthogonal projection of the canonical vectors of $R^3$ on S separately, would those 3 vectors be the orthogonal projection of $R^3$ on S?
and then each column of the requested coordinate matrix would be the coordinates of the projected vector obtained, now written in in the canonical base of $R^3$?
By the way, I can calculate the orthogonal projection of a vector on $S$ in the following way:
$(1 0 0)$ = $\alpha$ $v1$ + $\beta$ $v2$  + $\gamma$ $v3$ ,
where $v1$,$v2$ are the generating vectors of $S$ and $v3$ from $S^⊥$.I find  $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and the orthogonal proyection of  $(100)$ in $S$ is:
$P_S(1 0 0)$ = $\alpha$ $v1$ + $\beta$ $v2$.
right?
